# What are the uses of Method Handles in Java7?

Tags: java

I see there is a new thing added up in Java7 named method handlers. For what scenario they are useful for?

Comment: A link to the description of this new thing would be helpful...

Comment: Try http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=191 (A glimpse at MethodHandle and its usage)

Comment: JavaDoc of [MethodHandle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) looks very complete and explanatory.

Comment: C'mon, you can do better than this batman.  If we can find the link in 2 seconds with Google, then so can you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO It is a tool set ahead of its time. It is intend to replace reflections but has some performance issues (it can much faster or slower, but not consistently faster) It synatx is a bit cumbersome as well.

What is coming in Java 8 is closures and first class method references.  MethodHandles will play a big part in this and make their use/syntax natural and integrated. i.e. you will be able to use the new java syntax without having to refer to this class directly and the compiler will assist in the checking of types and exception throw in a way it cannot do with reflections now.  I assume by the time Java 8 is release its performance issues will be resolved as well.

Answer (score 7):

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-136358.html
>
> With the addition of support for JSR 292 in JDK 7, dynamically typed
>   languages should run faster in the JVM than they do today. A key part
>   of this support is the addition of a new Java bytecode, invokedynamic,
>   for method invocation, and an accompanying linkage mechanism that
>   involves a new construct called a method handle. These features enable
>   implementers of compilers for dynamically typed languages, that is,
>   the people who develop compilers for languages such as JRuby and
>   Jython, to generate bytecode that runs extremely fast in the JVM.
>
> ...
>
> A method handle is a simple object of type java.dyn.MethodHandle that
>   contains an anonymous reference to a JVM method. A method handle is
>   callable just like a named reference to a method. What makes it
>   unique, however, is that it is accessed through a pointer structure,
>   as opposed to a linked name.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Ain't Google grand?  I wonder why the OP didn't use it ;)  PS: I'm scared s***less of getting too involved in Java 7 specific code: I'm not at all confident in the future of Java now that it's fallen to Larry Ellison...  IMHO...

Comment: +1 for a reference to Google!

Answer (score 0):

> JDK 7 introduces a new player to this dynamic/runtime inspection, the method handle (i.e. a subclass of the abstract class java.dyn.MethodHandle). Method handles gives us unrestricted capabilities for calling non-public methods, e.g. it  can be formed on a non-public method by a class that can access it. Compared to using the Reflection API, access checking is performed when the method handle is created as opposed to every time the method is called.

Taken directly from [A glimpse at MethodHandle and its usage](http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=191)

At about that point I seg-faulted